# Callling the brk syscall using inline assembler

Tags: x86-64, inline-assembly, system-calls

How can I implement brk syscall in x86-64 linux? My code is as follows:

```
    Mysyscall(uint64_t n, uint64_t a1){
    uint64_t ret;
    __asm__ __volatile__("movq %0, %%rax\n\t"
            "movq %1, %%rdi\n\t"
            "syscall\n"
            : "=r"(ret)
            : "g"(n), "g"(a1));
    return ret; }

    Mysyscall(SYS_brk, uint64_t increment);
```

But it is not working. I think I may use wrong constraints for asm operands. but still find it difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not on linux, so I can't test this.  But based on http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64, I would expect it to be something like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("syscall"
        : "=a" (ret)
        : "0" (12), "D" (a1)
        : "rcx", "r11", "cc");
```

You may also need the "memory" clobber.

To learn about constraints, check out the i386 section here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html